# UITextView in UIModalPresentationFormSheet freezes app iOS 10

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitextview, ios10

I have a UITextView inside a view controller which I present using modal form sheet

```
vc.modalPresentationStyle = UIModalPresentationFormSheet;
[AppDelegate.rootController presentViewController:vc animated:YES completion:nil];
```

All was well till iOS 9.3. Then came iOS 10/10.0.1

With this, every time user taps inside the text field to bring up the keypad, the app freezes. I can't figure out why.
I tried making the UITextView as first responder. That fires up the keyboard just fine, I can type and hit a button on VC to take action. The VC and keyboard both gets dismissed. But again, if without hitting the button, if I try to simply dismiss the keyboard, app freeze.

Any ideas at all from anyone?

Comment: Do you have any solution for this issue? I am facing the same problem if I override the viewWillLayoutSubviews.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I moved my code to viewDidLayoutSubviews from viewWillLayoutSubviews. And it does not freeze anymore. Looks like an iOS 10 bug to me.

```
override func viewDidLayoutSubviews() {
    super.viewDidLayoutSubviews()
    self.view.superview!.bounds = CGRectMake(0,0, 500, 300)
}
```

Comment: This was the right solution. We realized for some reason viewWillLayout was getting called continuously thereby blocking any other app operation

Answer (score 1):

Was experiencing something like this earlier today.
The fix for me was as follows (unsure why, something must have changed in iOS 10).

In legacy code:

```
- (void)viewWillLayoutSubviews {
    self.view.superview.bounds = CGRectMake(0,self.view.superview.bounds.origin.y, 768, 256);
    [super viewWillLayoutSubviews];
}
```

Removing it fixed my issue.

Comment: Is the code that  you have here the solution? I tried the code below, and that still causes the freeze:     // THIS FUNCTION CAUSING FREEZE    
    override func viewWillLayoutSubviews() {
        self.view.superview!.bounds = CGRectMake(0,0, 500, 300)
        super.viewWillLayoutSubviews()

    }